# $\alpha $ and $\alpha^2 $ are the roots of the equation

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

$\alpha $ and $\alpha^2 $ are the roots of the equation $x^2+x+1=0$ then the equation whose roots are $\alpha^{31} $ and $\alpha^{62} $ is:
$$a). x^2+x+1=0$$
$$b). x^2-x+1=0$$
$$c). x^2-x-1=0$$
$$d). x^2-2x-1=0$$

My Attempt:

Since, $\alpha $ and $\alpha^2 $ are the roots of $x^2+x+1=0$ so,
$$\alpha + \alpha^2 = -1$$
$$\alpha.\alpha^2=1$$
...

Comment: Hint: $(x^2+x+1)(x-1)=x^3-1$ so $\alpha^3=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just found out that $\alpha^3=1$. Then, we get, $$\alpha^{31}=(\alpha^3)^{10}\alpha =\alpha \text{ and } \alpha^{62}=(\alpha^3)^{20}\alpha^2=\alpha^2$$

Thus, $\alpha^{31}$ and $\alpha^{62}$ satisfy the equation: $$x^2+x+1=0$$